# How is the opera-like voice in background called?

Tags: identify-this-genre

[Example Song 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrDG_HUIaOE)

[Example Song 2](https://youtu.be/_V_uMIfmaKg)

Is there a music genre with that characteristics?

Comment: Are you looking for a genre that has vocals like this combined with a beat like this, or just the vocals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you'll probably get to an identifiable genre for this vocal sound is **[epic choral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_music#Vocal) music** [(example)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuS27il9LAs) which is not so much a subgenre as the intersection between choral music and the loosely defined genre of cinematic music called "epic music."

The most well-known traditional classical piece in this style is probably [Carl Orff - "O Fortuna" from *Carmina Burana*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXFSK0ogeg4).